# Bash how to echo only the files that do not exist in a separate list of filenames?

Tags: bash

I'm having issues getting my code to just echo the file ID from a textfile if that file does not exist in my folder.

I have a directory with files named such as:

```
ASA11_mod_secun_2011.txt
ASB1133_mod_secun_2013.txt
BC09_mod_secun2_2011.txt
ASA111_mod_secun_2011.txt
```

And an `ids.txt` with IDs such as:

```
ASA11
ASB1133
BC09
ASA111
MK221
```

There is a file missing in my directory but because I'm working with hundreds of files and hundreds of IDs I just want to echo the ID in `ids.txt` that does NOT appear as part of a filename in my current directory. I want `MK221` to be echoed.

I've tried some variations of grep and for loops and I've gotten something like this, but I keep getting an error:

```
for i in $(cat ids.txt); do grep -v $i .; done
```

But this is opening every file in my directory rather than just printing the `$i` that does not appear in my directory.

I think an if then statement is probably what I need here but I'm not able to even come up with one properly. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) identifies several problems with the code.  The report that it produces includes links to more information about the problems and how to fix them.  It's a good idea to run [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) on all new and modified shell code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this:

```
while IFS= read -r line; do
    if ! compgen -G "${line}_"* &>/dev/null; then
         echo "$line"
    fi
done < /tmp/ids.txt
```

```
MK221
```

---

Don't try to use "for". Use a while loop and the read command.

http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001

---

`compgen` is a little hack to use the return shell code to test completions if file(s) exists:

`help compgen`

> compgen: compgen [-abcdefgjksuv] [-o option] [-A action] [-G globpat] [-W wordlist] [-F function] [-C command] [-X filterpat] [-P prefix] [-S suffix] [word]
>
> Display possible completions depending on the options.
>
> Intended to be used from within a shell function generating possible completions. If the optional WORD argument is supplied, matches against WORD are generated.
>
> Exit Status:
> Returns success unless an invalid option is supplied or an error occurs.

Comment: I need MK221 to print. I need the ID from the textfile to print out if there is no file that has that ID in the directory.

Comment: Fixed, thanks to report

Comment: Hey this worked great! Thanks so much. Never heard of compgen before so this is neat.

Answer (score 2):

Using `awk`

```
$ awk -F_ 'NR==FNR {a[$1]=$1;next} $1 != a[$1]' <(find /path/to/dir -type f -name '*.txt' -printf '%f\n') ids.txt
MK221
```

Answer (score -1):

First, lets find ids of existing files `shopt -s nullglob; for f in *_mod_*.txt; do echo "${f%%_*}"; done`. Here we use `${f%%_*}` to remove all characters after the first `_`, which is the ID of the filename. `shopt -s nullglob` to prevent if no matched files.

If we want to search sub-directories `shopt -s globstar nullglob; for f in **/*_mod_*.txt; do echo "${f%%_*}"; done`. Here we use `shopt -s globstar` to match zero or more sub-directories.

Then using `diff` command to compare the result:

`diff <(sort ids.txt) <(shopt -s nullglob; for f in *_mod_*.txt; do echo "${f%%_*}"; done | sort)`

or

`diff <(sort ids.txt) <(shopt -s globstar nullglob; for f in **/*_mod_*.txt; do echo "${f%%_*}"; done | sort)`

You will get this result: IDs that exist in the ids.txt file but have no corresponding file, and IDs that have a corresponding file but do not exist in the ids.txt file.

If you just want the IDs with no corresponding file:

```
diff <(sort ids.txt) \
     <(shopt -s globstar nullglob
       for f in **/*_mod_*.txt; do
         echo "${f%%_*}"
       done | sort
     ) | grep -F '<'
```